# Comparison of ways to pass data to Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I know of a few different approaches to getting 'stuff' into a Fragment, but in some cases I'm not confident I've rooted out all the 'devils in the details' and I haven't found a way I'm really happy with for passing complex objects or setting them on the fly:

1. Bundle (serializable/parcelable)
2. Persistent storage e.g. db/disk
3. Bundle + IBinder
4. Singleton/Application
5. Setters

My understanding of the tradeoffs are as follows:

1. Great for sending data/parameters, not-great for sending complex objects with behavior e.g. connections etc.
2. Great for reading data and displaying 'what currently is' and works across application lifetimes, may be awkward for 'display X now' type interface/infeasible for complex behavioral(wrong terminology?) objects
3. Haven't tried it, but sounds like a way to store an object handle in a Bundle? I'm unclear on what's required to make this work, other than extending Binder. Sounded too good to be true, especially since I haven't seen it advocated.
4. General design issues of using Singleton aside, this seems like possibly the 'safest' way for a Fragment to get access to a complex object?
5. Activity & Fragment lifecycle makes this really tricky to get right?

(4) and (5) are where I have the big ???'s over my head.

The reason I listed Singleton/Application as 'safe', is that while Fragments/Activities may be destroyed/recreated on a moment's notice (I've read that not even setRetainInstance is proof against this as that only deals with config changes), the Application instance is supposed to be persistent for the lifetime of the... application. So even if a Fragment/Activity instance gets destroyed and recreated, the new instance will always seek out the Singleton resource it was using before.

Setters seemed extremely convenient to me superficially, but if - for instance - after setting a Connection object on a Fragment, the system kills the fragment to reclaim memory (aside: can the system do this only to the fragment and not the activity? or are they always tied), I'm not aware of an elegant way for the Fragment to save its 'state' (complex object) to a bundle and restore it. Subsequently, AFAIK the fragment manager will create a new instance of the fragment, call a couple lifecycle methods, and pretend everything is hunky-dory, sans anything set via the Setter. So to fix this, I'm guessing I would be reliant on Activity lifecycle-restore to call the Setter again - but then the problem just recurses, i.e. if the Activity had a stored instance of a complex object, how is it supposed to restore *that* so it can restore it in turn to the Fragment?

In a complex project, this just seems to me like far too many moving pieces required to prove correctness of what boils down to "when I set X on Y, it gets set".

So my actual question is: Am I missing something? Is (4) as 'safe' as it looks, and do I have the right idea on the issues of (5) or is it better/worse than I've portrayed? Are there any extra 'gotchas' where things might be killed or might not get callbacks, or might get extra callbacks, or anything strange like that? Can (3) really be a magic bullet for saving/restoring handles to complex objects?

Comment: I always use #4 and as far as I know I've never gotten into a pickle. I don't even use an application instance but a POJO with an instance variable of itself. I know there are pages and pages arguing this but in my humble opinion they are academic arguments this setup just works in the real world.

Comment: I use an interface to exchange complex data between fragments and activity.  I just like the way the code stubs are written for me by the IDE when I implement interfaces.